# Ввести элементы двумерного массива с клавиатуры С++.

Tags: массивы

> Цитата

ВАЖНО : .Нужно вывести его на экран в виде таблицы. в конце каждой строки надо вывести самый большой элемент в каждой строке.

Вот мой код:

## include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h> using namespace std;

```
using std::cout; using std::cin;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { const int n = 4; const int m = 5;

int a[n][m]; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { cin >> a[i][j]; } } system("cls");

cout << "Initial array:" << '\n'; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { cout << a[i][j] << " "; } cout << '\n'; }

int count = 0; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { if (a[i][j] % 3 == 0 || a[i][j] % 5 == 0) { count++; } } } cout << "Count of elements which are multiple to 3 or 5: " << count << '\n';

int sum = 0; for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { if (a[1][j] % 2 == 0) { sum += a[1][j]; } } cout << "Sum of even elements of the second row: " << sum << '\n';

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { if (a[i][j] > 0) { a[i][j] = 0; } } }

cout << "Final array:" << '\n'; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) { cout << a[i][j] << " "; } cout << '\n'; }

return 0;
```

Я думаю что я делаю не то что нужно ... покажите в какую степь двигаться....

P.S. выдает ошибку fatal error C1075: конец файла обнаружен ранее, чем левая фигурная скобка "{" с.с\проекты\sortapp\sortapp\source.cpp(133)" , как её исправить?

Comment: отформатируйте код, и все станет ясно

Comment: Поддерживаю. Если вы напишите код лесенкой, ошибка станет самоочевидной.

Comment: Я не умею форматировать код  и дело тут не так как в ошибке , так в написании самого кода , я не могу вывести на экран сам массив,  самый большой элемент массива еще и в конце каждой строки...

Comment: @Facktor, так научитесь. Гуглите **как оформлять код** - код очень трудно читать, если он не оформлен отступами.

Comment: Неужели никто не поможет с решением?

Comment: @Facktor: Помощь в первом же комментарии. Сначала избавьтесь от этой проблемы, потом от других.

Answer (score 2):

```
int MaxElem(int arr[])
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max)
           max = array[i];
    }
    return max;
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        cout<<arr[i][j]<" ";
    cout<<"max of "<<i<<" row: "<<MaxElem(arr[i])<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо а можно полностью листинг? .... все равно не выходит макс. сумма...

Comment: что значит "полностью листинг"? чего вам не хватает? и да, одну мелочь пофиксил, невнимательность тому виной

Comment: @Макс Жуков, если уж на то пошло, то в `MaxElem()` цикл до `m` должен быть.